# Diagnosing Timeouts and Blocks on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, timeout, blocking

We found a scenario where a large delete in one table causes hanging across seemingly unrelated transactions and tables in the same the database (but not other databases on the same server). The good news is, using a combination of spwho2 and other commands, we found the query that causes trouble. This was all trial and error - and shutting things down until the symptoms subsided - but still we do not know the precise cause that leads to cascading blocks and timeouts - such as the exact lock or resource contention.

I started digging into this and got as far as enabling the "blocked process threshold" (set at 10 secs) and using a nice little util to parse the trace file: https://michaeljswart.com/2011/04/a-new-way-to-examine-blocked-process-reports/

We recreated the problem, and sure enough, we see plenty of "lead blockers" and then transactions that are waiting - but none of them are pointing to the large delete that we know to be the true cause. In other words, the lead blockers in the the blocked process report are likely victims themselves - so I am looking to connect the dots with the right diagnostics.

Any advice? As I am not a full time DBA, I am weighing a few things: Hiring a DBA to consult and evaluate, try a tool like SQL sentry, and stop here to talk to a community of pros where I might find some new quick leads.

Comment: Take a look at wait stats related to logging and hadr. The large delete may be slowing logging/commits for other transactions which will then hold locks longer and lead to more blocking.

Comment: What else do you have on the system? Mirroring, AG, memory-optimized anything, trace flags, anything else unusual? What process is actually at the top of the blocking list? Are there any `Flush Cache` or slow IO messages in the logs?

Comment: use sp_whoisactive with the `@get_locks =1, @query_plans = 1` parameters. This will show you the locks the delete is holding and also the execution plan, this may give clues as to what is happening. Some initial thought would be triggers and / or cascade deletes may be at play. You can log sp_whoisactive to a table: https://www.brentozar.com/responder/log-sp_whoisactive-to-a-table/

Comment: @Charlieface - hey Charlie - we have synchronous mirroring on - and last night I was able to see a bunch of threads waiting on DBMIRROR_DBM_EVENT

I'm guessing this creates some kind of single file line - all parallel transactions in the DB need to wait? It would appear that way. This is plenty to go on... spWhoIsActive FTW

Answer (score 0):

The large table that you are deleting from, does it have any foreign keys?  Do any of these foreign keys have DELETE CASCADE enabled?

You can use a variety of tools but you need to get the query plan and look at the wait stats to really understand what is going on.

Comment: Thanks. I just fired up sp_whoisactive logging stats and query plans to a table. Hopefully that gets me the diagnostics I need.